# Find Rating For Images using wordpress Plugin

Tags: javascript

I'm a newbie looking for help. What I want to do is this:

I am using orange-theme gallery in my wordpress

Now i want to find rating for each images click`s can u help me... or send any useful plugin in wordpress

Answer (score 0):

you can check pics mash plugin it works on wordpress 3.0 or higher http://wordpress.org/plugins/pics-mash/screenshots/

Answer (score -2):

That's a good photo rating plugin, that helped me create a voting for the best children's photo - http://wp-vote.net/ (WP Foto Vote)